# How to parse the date time and calculate if it is less than 2 days old from current date

Tags: java

Tried something like below, but getting the exception

```
Text '2023-06-12T10:49:010Z' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {HourOfDay=10, MinuteOfHour=49, NanoOfSecond=10000000},ISO resolved to 2023-06-12 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

```
public boolean compareDates(){
    String givenDate = "2023-06-12T10:49:010Z";
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSS'Z'");
    ZonedDateTime givenDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(givenDate, dateTimeFormatter);
    ZonedDateTime currentDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
    long daysDiffernce = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(currentDateTime, givenDateTime);
    return daysDiffernce < 2;
}
```

Any idea what's going wrong, is it something seconds is not correct means having three digits(010Z)

Comment: calculate the date for two days ago, and compare it to the one you've got

Comment: "but getting the exception" - what exception? I would strongly advise you to separate the problem into two parts: parsing from text to appropriate types, and working with those appropriate types. Chances are only one of those parts is relevant to the question - so cut the other one out.

Comment: "but getting the exception" <- What exception are you getting? The exception and the stacktrace is what will tell us and you what is wrong.

Comment: posted code does not compile, ergo it is not the correct one - and I would check the posted time '010' seconds is not *usual* (and ISO8601 formatted date/times don't need a formatter - it is the default format) - **and** `SSS` is fraction of seconds (intentional?)

Comment: **AND** the format `"...MM- dd..."` has an extra space that is missing in input (another copy&paste error? What else should we expect is missing?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ZonedDateTime you also have to specify a timezone. Easiest way would be to change your formatter to this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Also note that your pattern uses `SSS` which is milliseconds but I think you meant to use `ss` for seconds.
Uppercase S means milliseconds, lowercase s mean seconds. One is three digits the other is two.

Comment: Right that's what the issue is seconds should be two digits but here there are three do we need to ignore first Zero

Comment: If it's always a zero you could do  ```"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:'0'ss'Z'"``` but I think it would be better to clean up your input date if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the format does not conform to *[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)*.

There are three-digits in the *"seconds"* field.
And, these are subsequently identified as a *"milliseconds"* field—uppercase *"SSS"*.

There does not appear to be any way to include a *"wildcard"* within a parse pattern.
So, you'll have to remove the extra digit.
This could be either index 17, 18, or 19.

You can use the *[StringBuilder#deleteCharAt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt(int))* method.

```java
String givenDate = "2023-06-12T10:49:010Z";
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder(givenDate);
givenDate = string.deleteCharAt(19).toString();
```

Additionally, instead of typing out the pattern, you can use, *[DateTimeFormatter#ISO_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME)*.

```java
public boolean compareDates(){
    String givenDate = "2023-06-12T10:49:010Z";
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder(givenDate);
    givenDate = string.deleteCharAt(19).toString();
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
    ZonedDateTime givenDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(givenDate, dateTimeFormatter);
    ZonedDateTime currentDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
    long daysDiffernce = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(currentDateTime, givenDateTime);
    return daysDiffernce < 2;
}
```

Output

```
true
```